# Trouble in showing Surfaces in Grid using famo.us and meteor

Tags: meteor, famo.us

I am trying to show some surfaces in Grid using Meteor and Famo.us without any success. After I run the project locally, the browser shows a blank screen. For reference, I am looking at this example: https://famous-views.meteor.com/views/GridLayout

**HTML**

```html
<template name="gridTemplate">
    {{#GridLayout size='[undefined,undefined]' dimension='[3,3]'}}
        {{#famousEach items}}
            {{>ContainerSurface template='gridItem'  }}
        {{/famousEach}}
    {{/GridLayout}}
</template>


<template name="gridItem">
  {{#Surface  size='[undefined,undefined]'}}
    <img src="/img/thumbnail.png">
  {{/Surface}}

</template>
```

**Javascript**

```js
FView.ready(function(require) {
  FView.registerView('GridLayout', famous.views.GridLayout);
});


var items = [{
     name:"adfadf"
   },
   {
     name:"adfadf"
   },
   {
     name:"adfadf"
   },
   {
     name:"adfadf"
}];


Template.gridTemplate.helpers({
    items:function()
    {
        return items;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same error, and now found out that unfortunately the current famous-views for meteor has been deprecated in favor of a new version, which works with the newly released famo.us 0.5. and surfaces no longer work.

You can visit https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-famous-views to learn more about it, but help with the current famous-views will be difficult now, since all discussion is basically for the new version.

Let me know what you come up with, so far I'm testing it myself.